# Do electron have a rotational North/South and magnetic N/S?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons, quantum-spin, magnetic-moment, precession

Out of curiosity I wonder can an electron have a rotational North/true South which is different from it's magnetic North and magnetic South, if so can we measure the precession?

Comment: If by north south you mean the component of spin, then no. There is no preferred direction by a free electron. So you won’t have a repeatable experiment. Just statistical one.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, the question is whether the angular momentum of electron is aligned with its magnaetic momentum. If we're talking about a free electron, then no - the only source of the magnetic dipole moment of the electron is its internal angular momentum (spin), and the two are always aligned:
$$ {\bf \mu}_S = -g_s \mu_B \frac{\bf S}{\hbar}$$
where $g_s \approx 2$ (it's not exactly 2 because of quantum corrections).
But If we have an electron in a bound state, then it can also have some orbital angular momentum, which is also a source of magnetic dipole moment:
$$ {\bf \mu}_L - -g_L \mu_B \frac{\bf L}{\hbar}$$
where $g_L = 1$. Since $g_s \neq g_L$, then the total magnetic dipole moment of an electron, ${\bf \mu}_S+{\bf \mu}_L$ doesn't have to be colinear with the total angular momentum, ${\bf S}+{\bf L}$.